# How to realize in AJV Type definiton oneOf keyword?

Tags: validation, jsonschema, ajv

Does it exist in jtd standard way to realize `oneOf` behavior like in simple JSON schemas? Should I specify some custom keyword?

This code will throw error

```json
{

  "oneOf": [

    { properties: {... }},
    { properties: {... }}

  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem in`discriminator` form but I think is not direct alternative. Maybe, you can propose something better.